# how do you describe $a(x)$ with elementary functions? $a(x)=Ʒ_x(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, recurrence-relations

how do you describe $a(n)$  with elementary functions?

$$a(n)=Ʒ_n(1)$$

$$Ʒ_n(x)=\intƷ_{n-1}(x) dx+\frac{d}{dx}Ʒ_{n-2}(x)$$ where $Ʒ_0(x)=1$ and $Ʒ_1(x)=1$

I found $Ʒ_n(x)$ with $n$ between $1$ and $7$

$$Ʒ_1(x)=1,Ʒ_2(x)=x,Ʒ_3(x)=\frac{x^2}{2},Ʒ_4(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+1,Ʒ_5(x)=\frac{x^4}{24}+2x,Ʒ_6(x)=\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{3x^2}{2},\small \dots$$

$$a(1)=1,a(2)=1,a(3)=\frac{1}{2},a(4)=1+\frac{1}{6},\dots$$

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form for the sequence $a_n=Ʒ_n(1)$? So $a_1=1$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=2$, $a_4=5/2$, $a_5=8/3$, etc?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes

Comment: How did you obtain $Ʒ_3(x)=x+1$? If I computed correctly, we should have $$Ʒ_3(x)=\int Ʒ_2(x)\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}Ʒ_1(x)=\int x\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\mathrm{d}1}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{x^2}{2},$$ assuming that each antiderivative is always chosen so that it vanishes at $x=0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee  I'm setting the anti-derivative of 1 to be equal to x?

Comment: I have no problem with that, and that is why we obtain $Ʒ_2(x)=x$, i.e., $$Ʒ_2(x)=\int Ʒ_1(x)\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}Ʒ_0(x)=\int1\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\mathrm{d}1}{\mathrm{d}x}=x+0=x.$$ Then, when computing $Ʒ_3(x)$, you need "the" antiderivative of $Ʒ_2(x)=x$, which is why we must have the term $\frac{x^2}{2}$ in $Ʒ_3(x)$. And this is exactly what my previous comment is discussing.

Comment: @SangchulLee I think it's fixed

Comment: Hint: write $$3_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_{n, k} x^k$$ and derive a recurrence for $b_{n, k}$.

Comment: For any $n\geq1$, we have $$Ʒ_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/3\rfloor} \frac{n-3k}{n-2k} \binom{n-k-1}{k} \frac{x^{n-3k-1}}{(n-3k-1)!} $$